# chart.js add second line in a Line chart that starts from end of first line

Tags: javascript, chart.js, chart.jsv3

Im using chart.js and I have a line chart.I want to add a second line/dataset that starts from where the first line ends.

Ive seen people do this by adding `null` in the `data` property inside the `datasets` like this:

```
        type: "line",
        data: {
          labels: ["January,"February","March","April","May","June","July","August"],
          datasets: [
            {
              label: "My First Dataset",
              data:[4,5,6,7,8],
              fill: false,
              borderColor: "rgb(75, 192, 192)",
              tension: 0.3,
            },
    
            { label: "My First Dataset",
              data:[null,null,null,null,null,9,10,11],
              fill: false,
              borderColor: "rgb(75, 192, 192)",
              tension: 0.3,
            },
          ],
        },
      });
```

is there a different way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use object notation like so:

```js
const options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [{
          x: "Red",
          y: 5
        }, {
          x: "Blue",
          y: 3
        }, {
          x: "Yellow",
          y: 8
        }],
        borderColor: 'pink'
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [{
          x: "Yellow",
          y: 8
        }, {
          x: "Green",
          y: 5
        }, {
          x: "Purple",
          y: 3
        }, {
          x: "Orange",
          y: 8
        }],
        borderColor: 'orange'
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {}
}

const ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.5.1/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```